# R: Un-nest row indices

Tags: r, hierarchical-data

I have a dataframe like this:

```
type | length | freq 
-----|--------|------
 A   | 100    |  2    
 B   | 100    |  1
 A   | 200    |  1   
 B   | 200    |  0   
 A   | 300    |  3
 B   | 300    |  1
...
```

and I am using this code to generate *tidy data* from the freq column:

```
df <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$freq),]
df$freq <- NULL
```

which results in

```
    | type | length
----|------|--------
1.1 | A    | 100
1.2 | A    | 100
2   | B    | 100
3   | A    | 100
4.1 | A    | 300
4.2 | A    | 300
4.3 | A    | 300
5   | B    | 300
```

Note the nested row indices.

When plotting this as boxplots (`ggplot(df, aes(type, length)) + geom_boxplot()`), ggplot creates a boxplot for each type **and length**, probably because of the nested row indices.

(Side note: `write.csv(df, 'table.csv'); df <- read.csv('table.csv')` solves this problem)

Is there a way to unnest these row indices?

Comment: Use `row.names(df) <- NULL`. to reset them.

Comment: I already tried this. It does reset names of the row indices but their hierarchy is left intact.